# AWS cli. how to query snapshots and their name tags

Tags: aws-cli

first of all thanks for taking the time in helping me out on this one.

I have a 12300 long list of snapshots, working on deleting certain snapshots, so im trying to list them all first thru the CLI.

I want to get the SnapshotID, the StartTime, and from the tags, the 'Name'

I tried quite a few querys, but all of them result in null on the name :/
THsi is my latest one:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --query 'Snapshots[*].{ID:SnapshotId,Time:StartTime,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value[*]}'
```

Is this something one can do? or should i query all Key pairs, and then filter them out with --filters ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few issues to be considered:

- Beware of the type of quote marks around the Key Names(backticks, not single quotes)
- Forcing a single value out of the tag array.
- You should specify the `--owner-ids` otherwise all accessible snapshots will be listed (including ones that don't belong to your account)

This command works:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --query 'Snapshots[*].{ID:SnapshotId,Time:StartTime,Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value}' --owner-ids *<YOUR-ACCOUNT-ID>*
```

Comment: still no dice: 

    {
        "Name": null,
        "ID": "snap-xxxxxxx",
        "Time": "2018-02-09T08:07:57.000Z"
    },

Potential crucial detail i forgot to mention, im using the CLI on bash/ubuntu/windows.

Comment: Actually, i was doing an extra filter during testing that made your anwser not work correctly. THanks a lot @john-rotenstein !